# Compile-time Reflection of Nested List: typecheck List[List[Int]] returns List[List[...]]?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, typechecking

I'm using macro annotations to inspect the fields of a class and add a member based on those fields.

e.g.

```
@AddVal
class A(x: Int)
```

expands to

```
class A(x: Int){
  val get: Int = x
}
```

After extracting the`ValDef`, it's `tpe` field still `null` so to get the type I have two options:

1) If I call .toString on the type tree, I can see the type, but now I've lost some type-safety

2) If I use c.typecheck on the type tree, I can get the type, but only if it's 1 level deep. List[List[Int]] comes back as List[List[...]]

```
        val fieldType = c.typecheck(q"type T = ${f.tpt}") match {
          case x @ TypeDef(mods, name, tparams, rhs)  => rhs.tpe
        }
```

So, is there a way to recursively typecheck polytypes?

I tried typechecking `rhs` again but I got `The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known` and I'm not sure how to resolve that.

Thanks for taking a look,

Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I incorrectly attributed this error to the macro, when in fact there was *another* underlying macro (a type provider macro) that was failing to provide the proper nested type (in this case the `Int`).